# Applying onChange event on whole form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework (v3.2).
I am trying to apply `onChange` event on my `SimpleForm` so that I can work with all of the data that user puts into the form. However, the `onChange` event seems to be triggered only on the last input that is filled.

My onChange:

```
const handleChange = (event) =>
{
  setNewData(event);
};
```

And my SimpleForm:

```
<SimpleForm resource="msg" toolbar={null} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}>
   <ReferenceInput source="owner" reference="cmp" validate={required()}>
        <SelectInput optionText="name" />
   </ReferenceInput>
   <TextInput source="layout.caption" />
   <TextInput source="layout.text" multiline />
   <BooleanInput source="publish.active" defaultValue={true}/>
   <DateInput source="publish.dateStart" validate={required()} addLabel={true} label="resources.msg.fields.publish.dateStart" />
   <DateInput source="publish.dateEnd" validate={required()} addLabel={true} label="resources.msg.fields.publish.dateEnd" />
   {selectedValue !== null ?
     <TextInput source={`publish.users.${selectedValue}`} defaultValue={selectedIds} disabled={true} />
   : null}
</SimpleForm>
```

Any suggestions how can I get the data from the form?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use the onChange callbacks of the input elements, check the docs here: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html

Comment: @LuisGurmendez the thing is, I would like to have the values in object, so I can call a create function from my dataProvider later. I had this implemented back in the 2.9 version and it worked without a problem.

Comment: Well you can make the onchanges to mutate a single object, sorry I cant help you more. I’m not familiar with that lib, good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data from the `SimpleForm` to be object, you can get them using `FormDataConsumer`.

First you need to have a variable that will store the form data:

```
const [newData, setNewData] = useState(null);
```

Then in your form:

```
<SimpleForm resource="msg" toolbar={null}>
  <FormDataConsumer>
    {({ formData }) => formData &&
      <>
        <ReferenceInput source="owner" reference="cmp">
          <SelectInput optionText="name" />
        </ReferenceInput>
        <TextInput source="layout.caption" />
        <TextInput source="layout.text" multiline />
        <BooleanInput source="publish.active" defaultValue={true} />
        <DateInput source="publish.dateStart" validate={required()} addLabel={true} label="resources.msg.fields.publish.dateStart" />
        <DateInput source="publish.dateEnd" validate={required()} addLabel={true} label="resources.msg.fields.publish.dateEnd" />
        {selectedValue !== null ?
           <TextInput source={`publish.users.${selectedValue}`} defaultValue={selectedIds} disabled={true} />
        : null}
       {setNewData(formData)}
    </>
  }
 </FormDataConsumer>
</SimpleForm>
```

This you will have the form data stored in variable `newData`